# Polarity negative or positive on DC barrel jack?

Tags: power, dc, polarity, port

I have a DC port, can I make it positive or negative inside?

[image]

Comment: It is up to you how you hook it up.  It can be wired either way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which end of a barrel connector is positive?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/167204/which-end-of-a-barrel-connector-is-positive)

Comment: what makes you believe that a difference exists?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you control the wiring of the plug and the jack, you can choose either polarity for the inside contact. It is when you are connecting to an existing device that you have to conform to that devices convention. Note that most equipment has the inside contact as positive but not all.

Comment: Depends on the equipment. Many older devices commonly had negative on center, many modern devices commonly have positive on center.

Comment: @Justme  Notice the end of the last sentence "but not all".