# Will this power supply damage my gear?

Tags: power-supply, dc

I lost the power supply for my drumbrute, the manual doesn't have clear specifications of what the DC power supply is. But the back of my device says it takes a 12v 1a DC adapter. Would any 12v 1a DC adapter work for this device or is there some sort of hidden caveat? Does the mA of a power supply affect how it can work with my device?

Comment: Also: see Oli Glaser's answer concerning connector polarity, with the standard symbols, these must match on power supply and drumbrute: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33968/how-to-tell-polarity-expected-of-a-dc-barrel-jack

Answer (score 0):

The amp ratting specifies how much current the power supply can source to your device, if the device does not need it all then it wont use it all. So if you have a supply that is 12V at 5A and your device only needs 1A then it is fine since your device only draws as much as it needs.

Edit: YES like someone else mentioend it is very important to keep in mind the polarity of the connector. If you have a center positive power supply and your device is not as such you are in trouble.